# I am using react-native calendar-picker in react native . i want the date format DD/MM/YYYY as output

Tags: react-native, calendar, date-formatting

import moment from 'moment';

```
const { selectedStartDate } = this.state;
    const startDate = selectedStartDate ? selectedStartDate.toString() : '';
    const maxDate = moment(selectedStartDate, 'DD-MM-YYYY').format();
```

the outputs i am getting are
Mon Feb 08 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0530
2021-02-08T12:00:00+05:30

Comment: Show full code, where you are printing the date.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
const maxDate = moment(selectedStartDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer trying it own ...may help someone like me ..posting the code here.

```
import moment from 'moment';
//code to pick date into selectedStartDate here
const { selectedStartDate } = this.state;
const maxDate = moment(selectedStartDate).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
//write your calendar-picker code here
<View>
   <Text style={styles.details}>{ maxDate }</Text>
</View>
```

output: 05-02-2021